# uninitialized constant User::Post (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following problem, In UserController#show there has to be a list of posts, but it throws an error as shown in the screen shot: [image: screenshot page of the user]

The part of the code which is responsible to show user posts (show.html.erb)

```
<div class="span8">
<% if @user.posts.any? %>
  <h3>Работы (<%= @user.posts.count %>)</h3>
  <ol class="posts">
    <%= render @posts %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

posts.rb:

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
validates  :description, presence: true, lenght: { minimum: 6 }
validates  :user_id, presence: true
end
```

part of a code in user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

Your help, thanks in advance is very important.

Excuse for possible mistakes in the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should name your model in singular form:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
```